How can I solve error while installing R package "warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0' not found" problem?
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0' not found
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib' not found
ld: library 'emutls_w' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [treeclim.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘treeclim’
* removing ‘/Users/user/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/treeclim’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/user/Desktop/treeclim_2.0.6.0.tar’ had non-zero exit status

How can I solve this problem?
RStudio Version 2024.04.0+735
Apple M1 macOS Sonoma 14.5
sessionInfo() R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24) Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.5
I've installed tools (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/), but the problem was not solved
